# Stripping Punctuations using Python's .strip()

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why does `.strip()` not remove the punctuations when used as shown below, the way `translate()` does?

```
s = 'Hello world! Good-bye world?'
s = s.strip(string.punctuation + string.whitespace).lower()
```

gives: `'hello world! good-bye world'`

```
s = translate(None, string.punctuation)
```

gives: `hello world goodbye world`

Comment: Read the docs ;-)  Strip only works on the ends of strings, not the string interiors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a good language tool you may as well use nltk. Works very effectively for something like this and if you wanted to improve you could use the tokenizer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good discussion of this topic on the following thread: [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python)

One solution that I found there is:

```
re.sub('[%s]'%(re.escape(string.punctuation)),' ', s1)
```

If you want to replace with nothing - compression the punctuations then do:

```
re.sub('[%s]'%(re.escape(string.punctuation)),'', s1)
```

We build a character class being careful to escape the punctuation chars.  Then sub any of them with a space character.